# Weird printing behavior in Word Online & Excel Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-web-apps

We are using O365/SharePoint Online 2013.

Whenever our users try to print something via Word Online or Excel Online they get somehow weird results. Examples of these weird results are the loss of colors in Excel cells and also the overall shrinking of the document/spreadsheet. By shrinking I mean that spreadsheet dimensions look bigger before printing than they do on the preview and paper for example. Also there are URLs on top and bottom of the printed page.

So are there some settings we need to tweak to get the Word Online & Excel Online print documents and spreadsheets the same way as Word & Excel (to actually print them like they are seen in their digital form)? Or is this just one of the downsides of the Office Online/Web Apps?

EDIT: Well the problem persists and printing from Office Online apps is pretty much useless. The Office Online PDF/Print view where those documents and spreadsheets open before printing is the culprit. That viewer is the one messing up those documents/spreadsheets. :/

Thank you for any information regarding this matter!

Comment: Is Office Online covered in SharePoint SE?

Comment: @wjervis If by Sharepoint SE you mean Sharepoint Stack Exchange, then yes I'd think it is because I could find the "office-web-apps" tag and Office Online was previously known as Office Web Apps. :-)

Comment: It's a borderline question, but I see no reason to close it.